# Errror 503, HAProxy issue translating services across additional proxies, Docker, and LXD

Tags: linux, docker, load-balancing, haproxy, ubuntu-18.04

I do believe I am most likely having issues with my HAProxy file, but I am unsure. I have previously used this same config file to access other services in containers, as well as other services on other loadbalancers, as well as apache systems, and now I am unable to do so.

I do not believe that the other service is to blame, as they are native snap installs.

HAProxy status URI shows the status as L7STS/502, and attempting to load the pages for the port show as 503.

Before, a page was loading, but it was Nextcloud, and so I went into the Gitlab config.rb file, and changed the Default Port for NGinx from 80 to 8800, and ran the gitlab-ctl reconfigure command to rebuild Git onto the other port, and made the correction appropriately inside of HAProxy as well.

Other services that are not behind a proxy of any kind are loading just fine, and docker container services are not loading appropriately either, showing the same 503 error, which leads me further to believe its my HAProxy config file.

Here is a HAProxy Config File:

```
global
  log         127.0.0.1 syslog
  maxconn     1000
  user        haproxy
  group       haproxy
  daemon


defaults
  log  global
  mode  http
  option  httplog
  option  dontlognull
  option  http-server-close
  option  forwardfor except 127.0.0.0/8
  option  redispatch
  option  contstats
  retries  3
  timeout  http-request 10s
  timeout  queue 1m
  timeout  connect 10s
  timeout  client 1m
  timeout  server 1m
  timeout  check 10s
  errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
  errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
  errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
  errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
  errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
  errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
  errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http


###########################################
#
# HAProxy Stats page
#
###########################################

listen stats
  bind *:9090
  mode  http
  maxconn  10
  stats  enable
  stats  hide-version
  stats  realm Haproxy\ Statistics
  stats  uri /
  stats  auth -----:-----



###########################################
#
# Front end for all
#
###########################################

frontend ALL
  bind   *:80
  mode   http

  # Define path for lets encrypt
  acl is_letsencrypt path_beg -i /.well-known/acme-challenge/
  use_backend letsencrypt if is_letsencrypt

  # Define hosts
  acl host_horizon hdr(host) -i horizon.eduarmor.com
  acl host_eduarmor hdr(host) -i www.eduarmor.com
  acl host_nextcloud hdr(host) -i nextcloud.eduarmor.com
  acl host_git hdr(host) -i git.eduarmor.com
  acl host_minecraft hdr(host) -i mine.eduarmor.com
  acl host_sugar hdr(host) -i sugar.eduarmor.com
  acl host_maas hdr(host) -i maas.eduarmor.com
  acl host_rocketchat hdr(host) -i rocketchat.eduarmor.com
  acl host_hive hdr(host) -i hive.eduarmor.com

  # Direct hosts to backend
  use_backend horizon if host_horizon
  use_backend eduarmor if host_eduarmor
  use_backend nextcloud if host_nextcloud
  use_backend git if host_git
  use_backend minecraft if host_minecraft
  use_backend sugar if host_sugar
  use_backend maas if host_maas
  use_backend rocketchat if host_rocketchat
  use_backend hive if host_hive


###########################################
#
# Back end letsencrypt
#
###########################################

backend letsencrypt
  server letsencrypt 127.0.0.1:8888

###########################################
#
# Back end for Horizon
#
###########################################

backend horizon
  balance         roundrobin
  # option          httpchk GET /check
  option          httpchk GET /
  # http-check      expect rstring ^UP$
  default-server  inter 3s fall 3 rise 2
  server          server1 10.0.0.30:80 check
  #     server          server2 0.0.0.0:80 check



###########################################
#
# Back end for EduArmor
#
###########################################
backend eduarmor
  balance         roundrobin
  # option          httpchk GET /check
  option          httpchk GET /
  # http-check      expect rstring ^UP$
  default-server  inter 3s fall 3 rise 2
  server          server1 10.0.0.59:80 check
  #     server server2 0.0.0.0:80 check

##########################################
#
# Back end for Nextcloud
#
##########################################
backend nextcloud
  balance         roundrobin
  # option         httpchk GET /check
  option          httpchk GET /
  # http-check     expect rstring ^UP$
  default-server  inter 3s fall 3 rise 2
  server          server1 10.0.0.101:80 check


##########################################
#
# Back end, Gitlab
#
##########################################
backend git
 balance        roundrobin
 # option        httpchk GET /check
 option         httpchk GET /
 # http-check    expect rstring ^UP$
 default-server inter 3s fall 3 rise 2
 server         server1 10.0.0.101:8800 check



##########################################
#
# Back end, Minecraft
#
##########################################
backend minecraft
 balance        roundrobin
 # option        httpchk GET /check
 option         httpchk GET /
 # http-check    expect rstring ^UP$
 default-server inter 3s fall 3 rise 2
 server         server1 10.0.0.101:25565 check



##########################################
#
# Back end, PHPSugar
#
##########################################
backend sugar
 balance        roundrobin
 # option        httpchk GET /check
 option         httpchk GET /
 # http-check   expect rstring ^UP$
 default-server inter 3s fall 3 rise 2
 server         server1 10.0.0.101:80 check



##########################################
#
# Back End, MAAS
#
##########################################
backend maas
 balance        roundrobin
 # option        httpchk GET /check
 option         httpchk GET /
 # http-check   expect rstring ^UP$
 default-server inter 3s fall 3 rise 2
 server         server1 10.0.0.100:5240 check



##########################################
#
# Back end for Rocketchat
#
##########################################
backend rocketchat
  balance         roundrobin
  # option         httpchk GET /check
  option          httpchk GET /
  # http-check     expect rstring ^UP$
  default-server  inter 3s fall 3 rise 2
  server          server1 10.0.0.101:3000 check
  server          server2 10.0.0.102:3000 check



##########################################
#
# Back end for The Hive
#
##########################################
backend hive
  balance         roundrobin
  # option         httpchk GET /check
  option          httpchk GET /
  # http-check     expect rstring ^UP$
  default-server  inter 3s fall 3 rise 2
  server          server1 10.0.0.101:9000 check
  server          server2 10.0.0.102:9000 check
```

I would greatly appreciate any advice or insight into solving this problem, as well as any additional resources you may have on best practices, especially including configuring for SSL/TLS usage.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to comment out the option httpchk GET / comment, specifically for thehive backend, as well as shift away from using docker-compose to docker-swarm, which also substantially increased my knowledge as a whole of how docker works. The combination of issues from docker-compose combined with the / CHK was causing HAProxy to read the services as down, and returning a 503 error, which also meant it would never serve the services.

I would like to thank the anonymous person who volunteered their time to teach me docker-swarm and CI/CD processes tonight. I am much better for it than I would ever have been with being just spoon fed the answer, and I thank you so much for it, so do a lot of homeless veterans.